# Entity Framework: Не удалось найти файл метаданнах

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sql-server, entity-framework

Получаю вот такие ошибки при компиляции в VS 2013:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу понять в чем косяк... Все необходимые библиотеки подключены к проекту.

3 и 4 ошибка, при нажатии кидает в начало файла test.tt, а 1 и 2 в test.Context.cs и test.cs., где в файле содержится 1 строка `ErrorGeneratingOutput`

Вот так вот мне сгенерировался app.config(оставил только то, что касается EF):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.test.csdl|res://*/Models.test.ssdl|res://*/Models.test.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=octopus-elar;initial catalog=PWatcher;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Саму модель я создавал не в корне проекта, а в отдельной папке(Models).

---

Попробовал в корне проекта модель создать, но проблема такая же...

Модель я генерирую на основании существующей БД.

VS 2013 установлена не на диске с ОС.

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в том, что ранее VS2013 стоял на диске C, а потом была удалена и поставлена на диск D.

Однако, в переменной среды был указан диск С и после того, как я его поменял на диск D, все сразу же начало работать.

[Вот этот ответ помог.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031843/entityframeworks-dll-file-missing)